# AWS HTTP API Gateway 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have an HTTP API Gateway with a HTTP Integration backend server on EC2. The API has lots of queries during the day and looking at the logs i realized that the API is returning sometimes a 503 HTTP Code with a body:

```
{ "message": "Service Unavailable" }
```

When i found out this, i tried the API and running the HTTP requests many times on Postman, when i try twenty times i get at least one 503.

I then thought that the HTTP Integration Server was busy but the server is not loaded and i tried going directly to the HTTP Integration Server and i get 200 responses all the times.

The timeout parameter is set to 30000ms and the endpoint average response time is 200ms so timeout is not a problem. Also the HTTP 503 is not after 30 seconds of the request but instantly.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: try curl from the CLI to hit your server in the EC2

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the logs? Do you have the gateway logs enabled https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-logging.html ?

Comment: I have the logs enabled but I’m just getting the http codes, location of the request and some other data that is not useful for this case

Comment: @FaustoSanchez I have the same issue. Can you guide me on how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by editing the keep-alive connection parameters of my internal integration server. The AWS API Gateway needs the keep alive parameters on a standard configuration, so I started tweaking my NGINX server parameters until I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on a selfmade Microservice with Node that was integrated into AWS API-Gateway. After some reconfiguration of the Cloudwatch-Logs I got further indicator on what is wrong: `INTEGRATION_NETWORK_FAILURE`

### Verify your problem is alike - i.e. through elaborated log output

In API-Gateway - Logging add more output in "Log format"
[image]
Use this or similar content for "Log format":

```
{"httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod","integrationErrorMessage":"$context.integrationErrorMessage","protocol":"$context.protocol","requestId":"$context.requestId","requestTime":"$context.requestTime","resourcePath":"$context.resourcePath","responseLength":"$context.responseLength","routeKey":"$context.routeKey","sourceIp":"$context.identity.sourceIp","status":"$context.status","errMsg":"$context.error.message","errType":"$context.error.responseType","intError":"$context.integration.error","intIntStatus":"$context.integration.integrationStatus","intLat":"$context.integration.latency","intReqID":"$context.integration.requestId","intStatus":"$context.integration.status"}
```

After using API-Gateway Endpoint and failing consult the logs again - should be looking like that:
[image]

### Solve in NodeJS Microservice (using Express)

Add timeouts for headers and keep-alive on express servers socket configuration when upon listening.

```
const app = require('express')();

// if not already set and required to advertise the keep-alive through HTTP-Response you might want to use this
/* 
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.setHeader('Keep-Alive', 'timeout=30');
    next();
});
*/

/* ..you r main logic.. */

const server = app.listen(8080, 'localhost', () => {
    console.warn(`⚡️[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:8080`);
});

server.keepAliveTimeout = 30 * 1000; // <- important lines
server.headersTimeout = 35 * 1000; // <- important lines
```

### Reason

Some AWS Components seem to demand a connection kept alive - even if server responding otherwise (`connection: close`). Upon reusage in API Gateway (and possibly [AWS ELBs](https://connectreport.com/blog/tuning-http-keep-alive-in-node-js/)) the recycling will fail because other-side most likely already closed hence the assumed "NETWORK-FAILURE".

This error seems intermittent - since at least the API-Gateway seems to close unused connections after a while providing a clean execution the next time. I can only assume they do that for high-performance and not divert to anything less.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an AWS CDK Stack which created an ECS Cluster for some EC2 services which should be accessed using the API Gateway. But for some reason the API Gateway kept responding with "Service Unavailable", even though I was able to access it through the load balancer (after making the load balancer public temporarily).

I managed to fix the problem by setting `restrictDefaultSecurityGroup` to `false` when creating the VPC for the ECS cluster:

```js
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(
    this,
    'ClusterVpc',
    {
        maxAzs: 2,

        // Add this:
        restrictDefaultSecurityGroup: false,
    },
);
```

This disables the removal of certain security group rules which where needed for the whole thing to function.